# sox still doesn't support mp3 after its source is recompiled with mp3 support

Tags: mp3, centos, sox

I am trying to re-compile sox source with mp3 support on CentOS 5. Note sox-12.18.1-1.el5_5.1 has been installed on my CentOS machine for a while.

Following http://techblog.netwater.com/?p=4, I installed the following packages using yum.

```
yum install gcc-c++ libmad libmad-devel libid3tag libid3tag-devel lame lame-devel  flac-devel libvorbis-devel make
```

./configure shows the following.

```
BUILD OPTIONS
Debugging build............no
Distro name ...............not specified!
Dynamic loading support....no
Pkg-config location........$(libdir)/pkgconfig
Play and rec symlinks......yes
Symlinks enabled...........yes

OPTIONAL DEVICE DRIVERS
ao (Xiph)..................no
alsa (Linux)...............no
coreaudio (Mac OS X).......no
sndio (OpenBSD)............no
oss........................yes
pulseaudio.................no
sunaudio...................no

OPTIONAL FILE FORMATS
amrnb......................no
amrwb......................no
ffmpeg.....................no
flac.......................yes
gsm........................yes (in-tree)
lpc10......................yes (in-tree)
mp3........................yes
 id3tag....................yes
 lame......................yes
 dlopen lame...............no
 mad.......................yes
 dlopen mad................no
oggvorbis..................yes
sndfile....................no
wavpack....................no

OTHER OPTIONS
ladspa effects.............no
magic support..............yes
png support................no
GOMP support...............yes
```

But after executing "make && make install", issuing

```
sox test.mp3 tmp1.mp3 reverse
```

returns

```
sox: Failed reading test.mp3: Do not understand format type: mp3
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: This should help you.. Installing SoX w/ MP3 Support on CentOS 5.x
http://techblog.netwater.com/?p=4 :)

Comment: I know this is old, but the problem is that make install hasn't installed sox to a directory on your PATH, so you're still using version 12 rather than version 14.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Make sure that there is no other Sox installed on the server:

```
yum remove sox
```

Next:

```
make uninstall
make clean
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: That will not work if the original configure command doesn't include mp3